How to Join a Teams Meeting as a teams user using Azure Communication JavaScript Bundle
I am trying to join a teams meeting that created using graph API and trying to join to that meeting using azure communications JavaScript bundle. I can successfully join a ongoing teams meeting as external user (unverified user in teams) in azure communications callWithChatComposite.js.
Since I join the meeting as an external user I cannot start the meeting and need to wait till a verified user start the meeting(Lobby bypass access for the meeting generated is set to everyone). Following are the documentations I have followed and the code for join as an external user.
UI Composite Documentation: https://azure.github.io/communication-ui-library/?path=/docs/composites-build-your-own-javascript-bundle--docs
Front End: Angular
Back End: .Net
Join meeting as an external User:
Here accessToken generated from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/quickstarts/identity/access-tokens?tabs=windows&pivots=programming-language-csharp#create-the-access-tokens
const callComposite = await callWithChatComposite.loadCallWithChatComposite(
  {
    locator: { callLocator: { groupId: UUID }, chatThreadId: this.threadId },
    displayName: this.displayName,
    userId: {
      communicationUserId: this.communicationUserId,
    }, 
    token: this.accessToken,
    endpoint: this.baseUrl
  },
  document.getElementById('call-container'),
  {
    key: new Date()
  }
);

I have successfully created the token for a Teams User, and used following code to join the teams meeting as a Teams User.
Here accessToken generated from the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/quickstarts/manage-teams-identity?pivots=programming-language-csharp
const callComposite = await callWithChatComposite.loadCallWithChatComposite(
  {
    locator: { meetingLink: this.meetingURL },
    displayName: this.displayName,
    userId: {
      microsoftTeamsUserId: this.activeUserAzureId,
      isAnonymous: false,
      cloud: "public"
    },
    token: this.accessToken,
    endpoint: this.baseUrl
  },
  document.getElementById('call-container'),
  {
    key: new Date()
  }
);

I am getting following error for above code.
Error loading call composite: CallError: CallClient.createCallAgent: CallAgent must be created only with ACS token
When I use the accessToken like in the previous method, I can join the meeting but as an external user.
enter image description here
Need help to join the meeting from my teams account using azure communication UI Composite or need to know whether it is possible using own JavaScript bundle.
PS: I cannot use most of the libraries due to version incompatibility. That's why I use JavaScript bundle over recommended procedure.

Could you please refer this thread and let us know if it helps?

No. Seems like callWithChatComposite.js cannot be used to join a teams meeting as a teams user. Now I am trying to join the meeting using callComposite.js and trying to join the meeting and get following error.
call-with-chat.component.ts:116
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Microsoft Teams user identifier is not supported by AzureCommunicationCallAdapter. Instead use TeamsCallAdapter.
I can successfully join the teams meeting from my account using the token and id generated from public preview,

Need to figure out     const callAdapter = await callComposite.loadCallComposite();
object that need to pass to the loadCallComposite function.

@Prasad-MSFT Can you verify is it possible to use callComposite.js to join a teams meeting as a Teams User.

Azure Communication Services supports two types of Teams interoperability depending on the identity of the user: external user and Teams user. For Teams users, you should use the TeamsCallAdapter to join meetings and perform other actions. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/quickstarts/voice-video-calling/get-started-teams-interop?pivots=platform-web

@Prasad-MSFT I am using the static HTML Composite. I cannot install necessary libraries and that's why I am using this method.
https://azure.github.io/communication-ui-library/?path=/docs/composites-build-your-own-javascript-bundle--docs
I am struggling because in that documentation, it doesn't mention how to set the parameters for the loadCallComposite function. I just need to know what are the changes that need to do to the my above code.

The loadCallComposite function is part of the CallComposite class, which is used to configure and launch the Call Composite experience. The parameters you need to set for this function include activityContext, participants, and localOptions. https://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-android/azure-communication-ui-calling/com/azure/android/communication/ui/calling/CallComposite.html
